Promotional Ideas?
So how should we go about promoting the site, once it's live? I recognize some faces from the forums so obviously the links in our forum sigs worked, and I'm sure the link we placed on the Wiki did some good to, but that's not nearly enough. What other options can we come up with?

Including a link at bitcoin.org would be great. If the website proves to be helpful and builds a good community with high quality answers, we have a good chance of being accepted there. They used to link the bitcontalk forums.

I noticed that reddit also has some links on the right side. Does anyone know who is responsible for the reddit channel? Maybe we could get a "Bitcoin Q&A" link next to the "Bitcoin Forum".

used to host the forums...

I think that we can be a much better source for public knowledge than the forums. Where the forums were a place of discussion not necessarily friendly to "strong moderation" StackExchange has that in abundance. If we can keep the questions on-topic and downvote tinfoil hats and politically charged speech we should easily avoid the pitfalls that eventually separated the bitcoin forums from the main site.

+1'd because I've been a moderator on the forums for the past six months or so, and trying to create a productive atmosphere there is like trying to herd lolcats.

@eMansipater: Understandably more difficult! Forums are more conversational than SE (though less conversational than IRC) and should be more casual and chatty. It's not really the forums' fault, it's the nature of forums. We started this thing for a reason - not to slander the forums but to promote a different (separate but equal) environment for a different set of goals.

@nmat: Theymos is the moderator for the Bitcoin subreddit.

@Chris Acheson Thanks, I saw it now. Reddit's interface still confuses me a bit...

I think it would also be an excellent idea to have a channel that tweets interesting questions from the site with a link to them.  This alone would go a long way to getting people better informed about BitCoin, and I plan to do it if no one else does.

I love it! Does anyone know if SE has an API?

@David: It does.  The "api" link goes to http://stackapps.com/

Done: http://twitter.com/#!/BitcoinSE That's running off my work laptop at the moment but I can move it to a permanent home this evening assuming everyone approves. Also, I used the default Bitcoin logo until such a time as we decide on what else we're going to do for the site design.

Keep in mind that the site is still in private beta, so those links won't work for anyone!

Of course (well, unless they're also in the private beta). Just consider this twitter channel to be a "private beta" as well :)

Should I leave it at the default hashtag behavior, which is to use whatever the question was tagged as the hashtag or should I replace it with #bitcoin?

Probably #bitcoin should at minimum be added where space exists.

Hashtags have been changed and I've transferred the process to a PC at home. I'll try to get it a permanent home this weekend.

Is it possible to make it so that only questions with a certain number of upvotes get tweeted?  Otherwise it's just duplicating the RSS feed.

Yeah, it is, but only at 11+ votes which right now would give us something like 5 questions in the feed lol. Once public beta starts and the # of upvotes is more reasonable that can be changed in all of 5 seconds.

@David Probably a good idea to tweet those original questions again now that people can actually see them!

Good point, I'll delete all my old tweets and clear the twitterbot's memory when I get home tonight. Be prepared for a twitter-storm sometime around 6 or 7 PST.

@DavidPerry - I just asked a question about the Bitcoin.SE Twitter account. Looks like there's now an official one running - perhaps you'd like to tell followers at the account you created to go an follow the new one :-)

I think the biggest promotion will be simply in curating a site that is useful, drama and clutter free, and asks and answers interesting and important questions. I like the twitter idea, but AFAIK much SE traffic is driven by both search engines and regular users who return to browse.
